# ¿Cómo agrego el valor de un input a una clase?

Tags: javascript, html

Voy al grano, tengo una serie de elementos `input` con valores determinados y por otro lado un elemento `div` al que quiero agregar el valor del `input` seleccionado, es decir, el `:checked`, a su clase.

**Disparo HTML**

```html
<section>
  <div class="limit">
    <div class="cube">
      <!-- Contenido sin importancia -->
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="options">
    <div>
      <input id="front" name="option" type="radio" value="front" checked>
      <label for="front">front</label>
    </div>
    <div>
      <input id="back" name="option" type="radio" value="back">
      <label for="back">back</label>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

**Disparo Javascript**

```js
var cube = document.querySelector('.cube');
var options = document.querySelector('.options');
var current = '';

function rotate() {
  var checked = options.querySelector(':checked');
  var state = checked.value + '-state';
  
  if(current) {
    cube.classList.remove(current);
  }
  
  cube.classList.add(state);
  current = state;
}

rotate();

options.addEventListener('change', rotate);
```

El elemento al que quiero agregar el valor del `input` es el `div` que contiene `.cube`, de forma que tenga que alternar entre un valor y otro dentro de este elemento, dependiendo del `input` seleccionado.

**Ejemplo**

```html
<div class="cube front"></div>
```

o

```html
<div class="cube back"></div>
```

Llevo como una hora y el error que me sigue lanzando es: **options is null**

*Nota:* tengo la sensación de que el error es jerárquico. No sé cómo aún no he tirado el portátil por la ventana.

---

Lo curioso es que probando el código completo aquí, sí que funciona el Javascript, sin embargo en `localhost` no.

```js
var cube = document.querySelector('.cube');
var options = document.querySelector('.options');
var current = '';

function rotate() {
  var checked = options.querySelector(':checked');
  var state = checked.value + '-state';
  
  if(current) {
    cube.classList.remove(current);
  }
  
  cube.classList.add(state);
  current = state;
}

rotate();

options.addEventListener('change', rotate);
```

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  justify-content: center;
  margin: 1em
}

section {
  border: .0625em solid #98989d33;
  border-radius: 2px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
  padding: 1em
}

h1 {
  margin: 0;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%
}

.limit {
  border: .0625em dotted #98989d;
  height: 10em;
  margin: 1em;
  perspective: 30em;
  width: 10em
}

.cube {
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transition: transform 1s;
  width: 100%
}

.cube > * {
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%
}

.front {
  background-color: #ff375fcd;
  transform: rotateY(0deg) translateZ(5em)
}

.back {
  background-color: #32d74bcd;
  transform: rotateY(180deg) translateZ(5em)
}

.left {
  background-color: #0a84ffcd;
  transform: rotateY(-90deg) translateZ(5em)
}

.right {
  background-color: #bf5af2cd;
  transform: rotateY(90deg) translateZ(5em)
}

.top {
  background-color: #ac8e68cd;
  transform: rotateX(90deg) translateZ(5em)
}

.down {
  background-color: #ffd60acd;
  transform: rotateX(-90deg) translateZ(5em)
}

.options {
  width: 100%
}

.options div {
  margin-top: 1em
}

label {
  background-color: #ffd60a;
  border-radius: 2px;
  font-family: monospace;
  padding: .25em
}

input:checked + label {
  color: #ff375f
}

.front-state { transform: translateZ(-5em) rotateY(0deg) }
.back-state { transform: translateZ(-5em) rotateY(-180deg) }
.left-state { transform: translateZ(-5em) rotateY(90deg) }
.right-state { transform: translateZ(-5em) rotateY(-90deg) }
.top-state { transform: translateZ(-5em) rotateX(-90deg) }
.down-state { transform: translateZ(-5em) rotateX(90deg) }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Lab</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <section>
      <h1>Cubo</h1>
      <div class="limit">
        <div class="cube">
          <div class="front"></div>
          <div class="back"></div>
          <div class="left"></div>
          <div class="right"></div>
          <div class="top"></div>
          <div class="down"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="options">
        <div>
          <input id="front" name="option" type="radio" value="front" checked>
          <label for="front">front</label>
        </div>
        <div>
          <input id="back" name="option" type="radio" value="back">
          <label for="back">back</label>
        </div>
        <div>
          <input id="left" name="option" type="radio" value="left">
          <label for="left">left</label>
        </div>
        <div>
          <input id="right" name="option" type="radio" value="right">
          <label for="right">right</label>
        </div>
        <div>
          <input id="top" name="option" type="radio" value="top">
          <label for="top">top</label>
        </div>
        <div>
          <input id="down" name="option" type="radio" value="down">
          <label for="down">down</label>
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: encontraste solución a tu problema???

Comment: Aún no, he probado la solución de una de las respuestas pero el error que me da es `options is undefined`.

Answer (score 0):

Tu variable "options" esta tratando de obtener el valor pero del contenedor con la clase .options mas no el de los radios. Intenta obtener los valores del radio por el atributo name.

```
var options = document.getElementsByName('option').value;
```

Comment: Lo he probado pero no funciona, es decir, reemplazar el valor de `options` al inicio del script, pero nada. No permuta los dos valores que quiero. El error que dispara es `options is undefined`.

Answer (score 0):

entiendo que quieres añadir el nombre de la cara seleccionada del cubo. A tu código he añadido:

en el JS:

```js
var cubeDivs = document.querySelectorAll(".cube div");
```

Esto selecciona todas las caras del cubo.

Al principio de la función `rotate()`he añadido:

```
  // para cada carra del cubo
  cubeDivs.forEach(cd => {
    //borra el contenido html
    cd.innerHTML = "";
  });

  var checked = options.querySelector(":checked");
  // selecciona el elemento cuya clase es el valor checked.value
  // y dale un innerHTML que es igual al checked.value
  cube.querySelector("." + checked.value).innerHTML =
    "<p>" + checked.value + "</p>";
```

En el CSS he añadido algunas reglas para centrar el texto:

```
.cube div p {
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 1em;
  margin: auto;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

Espero que esto sea lo que preguntabas:

```js
var cube = document.querySelector(".cube");
var cubeDivs = document.querySelectorAll(".cube div");
var options = document.querySelector(".options");
var current = "";

function rotate() {
  
  
  
  cubeDivs.forEach(cd => {
    cd.innerHTML = "";
  });
  var checked = options.querySelector(":checked");
  cube.querySelector("." + checked.value).innerHTML =
    "<p>" + checked.value + "</p>";
  
  
  
  

  var state = checked.value + "-state";

  if (current) {
    cube.classList.remove(current);
  }

  cube.classList.add(state);
  current = state;
}

rotate();

options.addEventListener("change", rotate);
```

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  justify-content: center;
  margin: 1em;
}

section {
  border: 0.0625em solid #98989d33;
  border-radius: 2px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
  padding: 1em;
}

h1 {
  margin: 0;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
}

.limit {
  border: 0.0625em dotted #98989d;
  height: 10em;
  margin: 1em;
  perspective: 30em;
  width: 10em;
}

.cube {
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transition: transform 1s;
  width: 100%;
}

.cube > * {
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
}

.front {
  background-color: #ff375fcd;
  transform: rotateY(0deg) translateZ(5em);
}

.back {
  background-color: #32d74bcd;
  transform: rotateY(180deg) translateZ(5em);
}

.left {
  background-color: #0a84ffcd;
  transform: rotateY(-90deg) translateZ(5em);
}

.right {
  background-color: #bf5af2cd;
  transform: rotateY(90deg) translateZ(5em);
}

.top {
  background-color: #ac8e68cd;
  transform: rotateX(90deg) translateZ(5em);
}

.down {
  background-color: #ffd60acd;
  transform: rotateX(-90deg) translateZ(5em);
}

.options {
  width: 100%;
}

.options div {
  margin-top: 1em;
}

label {
  background-color: #ffd60a;
  border-radius: 2px;
  font-family: monospace;
  padding: 0.25em;
}

input:checked + label {
  color: #ff375f;
}

.front-state {
  transform: translateZ(-5em) rotateY(0deg);
}
.back-state {
  transform: translateZ(-5em) rotateY(-180deg);
}
.left-state {
  transform: translateZ(-5em) rotateY(90deg);
}
.right-state {
  transform: translateZ(-5em) rotateY(-90deg);
}
.top-state {
  transform: translateZ(-5em) rotateX(-90deg);
}
.down-state {
  transform: translateZ(-5em) rotateX(90deg);
}

.cube div p {
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 1em;
  margin: auto;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<section>
      <h1>Cubo</h1>
      <div class="limit">
        <div class="cube">
          <div class="front"></div>
          <div class="back"></div>
          <div class="left"></div>
          <div class="right"></div>
          <div class="top"></div>
          <div class="down"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="options">
        <div>
          <input id="front" name="option" type="radio" value="front" checked>
          <label for="front">front</label>
        </div>
        <div>
          <input id="back" name="option" type="radio" value="back">
          <label for="back">back</label>
        </div>
        <div>
          <input id="left" name="option" type="radio" value="left">
          <label for="left">left</label>
        </div>
        <div>
          <input id="right" name="option" type="radio" value="right">
          <label for="right">right</label>
        </div>
        <div>
          <input id="top" name="option" type="radio" value="top">
          <label for="top">top</label>
        </div>
        <div>
          <input id="down" name="option" type="radio" value="down">
          <label for="down">down</label>
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>
```

Comment: No entiendo por qué añadir un elemento `p` si en el HTML no hay ninguno. Sigue disparándome el mismo error: `options is null`. Lo curioso es que el código Javascript está bien, solo que no entiendo por qué funciona correctamente en Stack Overflow, pero aparte (`localhost`) no.

Comment: Funciona correctamente en Codepen también. El elemento p lo utilizo para añadir texto a las caras del cubo

Comment: Cierto. Pues no sabía detectar el problema, la verdad, no manejo muy bien Javascript.